# How to invoke this function?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, cextension

Below sample i saw in Apple document, confused about how to call `qsort_b` fucntion? What are the parameters need to pass as  `const void *l` & `const void *r`.

```
char *myCharacters[3] = { "TomJohn", "George", "Charles Condomine" };
qsort_b(myCharacters, 3, sizeof(char *), ^(const void *l, const void *r) {
    char *left = *(char **)l;
    char *right = *(char **)r;
    return strncmp(left, right, 1);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, the difference between `qsort` from the standard C library and `qsort_b` is that `qsort_b` takes a [*block*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH7-SW1), rather than a function pointer:

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nel, size_t width, int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));

void qsort_b(void *base, size_t nel, size_t width, int (^compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

The purpose of the block is the same as that of the comparison function - determining whether the two elements of the array are equal, or if they are not, which one is greater than the other.

> What are the parameters need to pass as `const void *l` & `const void *r`?

It's not you who pass these parameters: these parameters are passed back to your comparison block by `qsort_b`. The first parameter is the value of the left element being compared; the second one is the element on the right.